# What is a cleaner way to calculate percentage when dividing an integer by another integer in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

New hobbyist tinkerer trying to divide 2 integers. The idea is to simply take `currentpts` and divide it by `totalpts` to see what the percentage complete is. Both `currentpts` and `totalpts` will always be an integer.

The following code worked but I'm curious if there is a more preferable way to do this. I have the following in my View file.

```
<td>
  <%= number_to_percentage(todo_item.currentpts/todo_item.totalpts.to_f*100, precision: 0) %>
</td>
```